# When flexbox is set to align and justify all items as center, why is the text not centered?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to flexbox. My goal with the code is to vertically and horizontally center the text in the container div.

Why isn't the text being center aligned? Do I need to add a `text-align:center`? Shouldn't flexbox be doing that for me?

```css
.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #efefef;
}

.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div>Some text here and here and here...</div>
    <div>a little less text...</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting flex on the `.container`, whose only child is `.content`, which is centered.

Applying `text-align: center` should align the text within that div to the center.

The divs inside `.content` are still block level elements with text aligned to the left.  Setting flex on a container won't affect children of children.

Borders and backgrounds added for clarity.

```css
.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #efefef;
}

.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 24px;
}

.content > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div>Some text here and here and here...</div>
    <div>a little less text...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my question is do I need to specifically apply "text-align" shouldn't flex-box center, center the text? Or when centering text with flexbox, do you also have to use text-align: center? To fully center the text?

Comment: Added a snippet to the answer to try and illustrate more.  Does that help explain why you still need to specify text alignment?

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is doing its job here. You have text-align set to the default, left. If you want it centered, then yes you will have to use text-align: center; on the div that contains the text you want centered.

```css
.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #efefef;
}

.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div>Some text here and here and here...</div>
    <div>a little less text...</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flex properties only works on flex row and flex items not to inner elements of flex items.

Here your flex container is `.container` and flex item is `.content`...`align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` will only work on flex-items.

You will need to use `text-align:center` to align the text in center

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #efefef;
}

.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div>Some text here and here and here...</div>
    <div>a little less text...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another solution is to apply the `display:flex` to the `.content` with `align-items:center`...you will understand the concept of flex...

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #efefef;
}

.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div>Some text here and here and here...</div>
    <div>a little less text...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```